# How to apply Durandal Transitions to an element instead of a view?

Tags: knockout.js, single-page-application, durandal

I have a list of elements that the user can add to / remove from.  Can someone provide an example of how one might apply transitions to these individual elements, instead of a whole view?

Comment: jquery animate or css3 transitions

Comment: @RobVious were you able to acheive this ? I am using https://gist.github.com/jstott/6326038 for transitions. But I don't want it for the whole page. Just a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't Durandal specific, it's something Knockout would handle:

http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html

Ignore answers that have you fiddle with the DOM outside of Knockout.  That's what KO helps you with.

An example:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.animateForeach = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
            return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel)
        },
        update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, context) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())
            var newAccessor = function() {
                return {
                    data: value,
                    afterAdd: function(node) {
                        $(node).hide()
                        $(node).slideDown('fast')
                    },
                    beforeRemove: function(node) {
                    if (node.nodeType === 1) {
                        $(node).slideUp('fast', function() {
                            $(this).remove()
                        })
                    }
                }
                }
            }
            return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update(element, newAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, context)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to use isotope to add or remove images then you activate isotope inside the

```
function viewActivate(){
    $("#container").isotope({
        layoutMode: "masonry",
        itemSelector: ".photo"
    });
}
```

whatever JavaScript callback you want to use to add or remove images

```
function addRemoveImages(newimage)
{
    $("#container").isotope('insert', newimage); //This will cause isotope to re-animate only the content not the view 
}
```